# PHP actions if checkboxes are selected!

Tags: php

I have a form with 3 checkboxes, and my idea is run some commands if they are selected and do something else if they are not selected.

```
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
{
    if ($_POST['option'.$i])
    {
    echo "123";
    }
    if (!$_POST['option'.$i]) 
    {
    echo "456";
    }
}
```

But if they are not selected the commands are not executed.. The if statement is correct?

Comment: Haven't actually tried it???  You should use if/else rather than 2 if conditions, for one.

Comment: @Fosco Testing is for nood dude. Great coders does the right code from the begining !

Comment: If these are checkboxes, why are they in a loop?

Comment: @Brandon Ellis That's just how he's stepping through the options.

Answer (score 6):

No, what you should be doing is checking them like this:

`if (isset($_POST['option'.$i]))`

Otherwise, you are just trying to evaluate the boolean form of whatever is in that $_POST element.  Why is this bad?  Suppose the value of that field were `0`.  Even though the checkbox was checked, your code wouldn't run.

[Documentation for `isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that will work just fine.

If you want to slightly de-uglify your code, you can do it this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[option_name]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[second_option_name]" value="1" />

if(isset($_POST['options']) && is_array($_POST['options']) {
  foreach($_POST['options'] as $option_name => $ignore_this) {
    switch($option_name) {
      case 'option_name':
        // do something
        break;
      case 'second_option_name':
        // do something else
        break;
  }
}
```

}

Comment: no, it will give a notice on accessing an uninitialized value of the array if the checkbox is not checked.

Comment: If you have E_NOTICE turned on, which your average PHP installation won't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if ... else:

```
  if ($_POST['option'.$i])
   {
      echo "123";
   }
   else 
   {
     echo "456";
   }
```

to avoid checking the same condition twice.